# Why do Mike and Tuco have the same boxing charm?

Tags: plot-explanation, better-call-saul

At the beginning of *Better Call Saul* S2E04, we see Mike sitting on his couch admiring some kind of boxing gloves charm.

[image]

And then, later in the episode when Mike confronts Tuco Salmanca, Tuco is shown wearing the exact same boxing gloves charm.

[image]

Mike and Tuco get into a fight and Mike grabs Tuco by the shirt (near the charm) **but Mike never rips Tuco's necklace off**.

[image]

#### If Mike never took Tuco's necklace then how does he now have it (assuming that it is in fact the exact same charm)? *Why would Mike even want it?*

Comment: is it possible that Mike or someone in his family, has won the golden gloves in amateur boxing? and that Tuco has silver, runner-up, from his time? i'm also curious, as i don't actually know what kind of award they distribute for the winner of the golden gloves

Comment: I feel like it is the same gloves but it seems to be golden in colour in the dim-light. And considering Tuco has the same charm in Breaking Bad, there "might" be a future plot-line where Tuco and Mike meets again and perhaps Mike gives away the charm?

Comment: @NikhilEshvar I think. that's the answer

Comment: @NicholasAysen They do award something similar but I don't think they are as "blinged" as the ones in the image.

Comment: Seems like clever foreshadowing. Hell, even the episode's name is gloves off. We may know the reason in a future episode.

Answer (score 2):

The boxing glove necklace is one and the same. Period. Whilst all film & TV productions are obviously artificially lit, the lighting director on this show does an exceptional job... that being said:

The lighting in Mike's house is an artificial small side lamp with no exterior light; or even TV (very warm and subdued): [image: Souvenir]

and whilst the El Michoacona restaurant interior is not in direct sunlight, Tuco is sitting front and centre before two huge open panes flooding in scads of Albuquerque ambient sunlight; giving the impression of a more silvery metal:[image]

Head outside, where our combatants are squaring up in the shade, and the gloves are looking more like the prize Mike is admiring as he licks his wounds in the pre-credit post scene:[image]

~ All these tales of Golden Gloves and past glories are pure nonsense. And just because the director doesn't show Mike ripping the charm from Tuco's chest, doesn't indicate proof of there having to be two separate 'Mr.T hand-me-downs'.

Comment: Thanks for this response. After reconsideration and a closer look, I now believe both gloves to be silver. Unfortunately though, w.r.t. your response, it does actually answer my question (which is, why do Mike and Tuco have the same boxing charm?).

Comment: Unfortunately, it _does_ actually answer your question. Huh? Is this a typo?
I see cheap plated gold myself, not silver. But no matter you accept they're the same. But are you still stuck on the fact the scene didn't literally show Mike ripping the necklace off of Tuco?

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, I meant to say *does **not***. *But are you still stuck on the fact the scene didn't literally show Mike ripping the necklace off of Tuco?* -- Yes. An action as significant as Mike stealing what seems to be Tuco's necklace, Tuco not noticing it and/or not pursuing after Mike for it, *and* there being no apparent motive behind Mike doing so, leaves on the table a good number of unanswered questions. As several others have commented, the opening scene of that episode could very well be a moment in the somewhat distant future (i.e., several episodes or a season forward).

Comment: There's no way Mike could have ripped the boxing charms off Tuco's neck in that brief altercation. If you look closely, the boxing gloves are attached to a closed loop that the necklace itself feeds though. Mike would have had to of jerked the entire necklace off Tuco and he'd for sure notice that. Having an opening scene feature such a significant plot element but then not explicitly show how it came into Mike's possession is extremely, *extremely* unlikely.

Comment: You don't need to see the necklace being actually torn off to understand that the opening scene is immediately after Mike has met with Nacho (end of episode) and been given an envelope of 25 large in cash. The same envelope he drops on his kitchen table on returning home. You know, with his face beaten to a pulp.
You seem set on making this far more complicated than it is... how would it be some weeks in the future, and why? I do wish you were more of a Charles McGill and I could stop banging my head against this brick wall.
**You're done. You are done!**

Comment: I think you should relax. As a final comment to this conversation, your answer makes no attempt of explaining ***how*** Mike got the charm or ***why*** he would even want it, and those are the two focal points of the OP. The question was never alone, *"are the two charms the same?"*, and I do welcome you to edit your answer if you feel you can address the main concerns of the OP.

Comment: haha. The "You're done" line is just a joke from BCS 502 btw. As uttered by Mike - Do you not watch the show anymore? But Like I said, I'd be wasting my time trying to convince you as you seem dead set on the explanation having to be grounded in actual reality, rather than implied. So I don't believe you'll ever accept an answer.

Comment: But in closing myself, you must be aware that it's a standard movie trope that all necklaces are just plucked from lovers/enemies, etc. And Tuco is about to be piled on by several uniformed officers after putting Mike down with his last incriminating punch - the last thing on his mind would be how straight his jewellery is. Go watch the episode again. Take notes. Learn a bit of critical analysis, but I'm going to leave you to it Chuck mate.